# How to implement expandable rows in html with dynamic depth in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, html-table

I need to create a table in angularjs where rows can be expanded to the depth until the key "children.contains" has no child ids. I have created the basic example in plunker but I need to generate child rows dynamically. How to do that? Also in my code, For every child row, I need to iterate the whole json array to fetch its children. It is making the loading of table very slow. Is there any other effective solution for this? Please help

Here is the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/oZqeYCXqc44626lY4Mql?p=preview

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.1" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="DealersCtrl as ctrl">
    <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.expandAll(allExpanded = !allExpanded)">
                        <span ng-bind="allExpanded ? '-' : '+'"></span>
                    </button>
                </th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Child</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>s
            <tr ng-repeat-start="dealer in dealers[0].Items" ng-show = "dealer.Parent">
                <td>
                    <button ng-click="expanded = !expanded" expand>
                        <span ng-bind="expanded ? '-' : '+'"></span>
                    </button>
                </td>
                <td ng-bind="dealer.name"></td>
                <td ng-bind="dealer.ID"></td>
                <td ng-bind="dealer.children.contains"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="expanded">
                <td></td>
                <td colspan="6">
                    <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat-start="brand in dealers[0].Items" ng-show = "containsKey(brand.ID,dealer.children.contains)">
                                <td>
                                    <button ng-click="expandedChild1 = !expandedChild1" expand>
                                        <span ng-bind="expandedChild1 ? '-' : '+'"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </td>

                                <td ng-bind="brand.name"></td>
                                <td ng-bind="brand.ID"></td>
                                <td ng-bind="brand.children.contains"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="expandedChild1">
                                <td></td>
                                <td colspan="6">
                                    <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr ng-repeat="brand1 in dealers[0].Items" ng-show = "containsKey(brand1.ID,brand.children.contains)">
                                                <td>
                                                    <button ng-click="expanded1 = !expanded1" expand>
                                                        <span ng-bind="expanded1 ? '-' : '+'"></span>
                                                    </button>
                                                </td>

                                                <td ng-bind="brand1.name"></td>
                                                <td ng-bind="brand1.ID"></td>
                                                <td ng-bind="brand1.children.contains"></td>
                                            </tr>

                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.28" data-semver="1.2.28" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-resource@1.2.28" data-semver="1.2.28" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  angular.module('myApp',[])
    .controller('DealersCtrl', function($scope) {
      var self = this;


      self.expandAll = function(expanded) {
        // $scope is required here, hence the injection above, even though we're using "controller as" syntax
        $scope.$broadcast('onExpandAll', {
          expanded: expanded
        });
      };
      $scope.containsKey = function(key,array)
      {
        if(array.length > 0 && array.indexOf(key) > -1)
          {return true;}
        else
          {return false;}
      }
      $scope.dealers=[{
           "Items" : [ {
           "ID" : "8008_1",
           "name" : "data1",
           "children" : {
           "contains" : [ "8013_1", "8022_1", "8010_1", "8024_1", "8009_1", "8017_1" ]
           },
           "Parent" : false
           }, {
           "ID" : "8009_1",
           "name" : "data2",
           "children" : {
           "contains" : [ ]
           },
           "Parent" : false
           }, {
           "ID" : "8015_1",
           "name" : "data3",
           "children" : {
           "contains" : [ ]
           },
           "Parent" : false
           }, {
           "ID" : "8023_1",
           "name" : "data4",
           "children" : {
           "contains" : [ ]
           },
           "Parent" : false
           }, {
           "ID" : "8020_1",
           "name" : "data5",
           "children" : {
           "contains" : [ ]
           },
           "Parent" : false
           }, {
           "ID" : "8007_1",
           "name" : "data6",
           "children" : {
           "contains" : [ "8008_1" ]
           },
           "Parent" : false
           }, {
           "ID" : "8011_1",
           "name" : "datat7",
           "children" : {
           "contains" : [ "8012_1" ]
           },
           "Parent" : false
           }, {
           "ID" : "8018_1",
           "name" : "datat8",
           "children" : {
           "contains" : [ "8020_1", "8021_1", "8019_1" ]
           },
           "Parent" : false
           }, {
           "ID" : "8001_1",
           "name" : "datat9",
           "children" : {
           "contains" : [ "8002_1" ]
           },
            "Parent" : true
           }, {
           "ID" : "8013_1",
           "name" : "datat9",
            "children" : {
           "contains" : [ "8014_1" ]
           },
           "Parent" : false
           }, {
           "ID" : "8019_1",
           "name" : "datat10",
           "children" : {
           "contains" : [ ]
           },
           "Parent" : false
           }, {
           "ID" : "8021_1",
           "name" : "datat11",
           "children" : {
           "contains" : [ ]
           },
           "Parent" : false
           }, {
           "ID" : "8010_1",
           "name" : "datat12",
           "children" : {
           "contains" : [ "8011_1" ]
           },
           "Parent" : false
           }, {
           "ID" : "8006_1",
           "name" : "datat12",
           "children" : {
           "contains" : [ ]
           },
           "Parent" : false
           }, {
           "ID" : "8014_1",
           "name" : "Mobile Data",
           "children" : {
           "contains" : [ "8016_1", "8015_1" ]
           },
           "Parent" : false
           }, {
           "ID" : "8016_1",
           "name" : "datat14",
           "children" : {
           "contains" : [ ]
           },
           "Parent" : false
           }, {
           "ID" : "8025_1",
           "name" : "datat15",
           "children" : {
           "contains" : [ ]
           },
           "Parent" : false
           }, {
           "ID" : "8024_1",
           "name" : "datat16",
           "children" : {
           "contains" : [ "8025_1" ]
           },
           "Parent" : false
           }, {
           "ID" : "8003_1",
           "name" : "data17",
           "children" : {
           "contains" : [ ]
           },
           "Parent" : false
           }, {
           "ID" : "8004_1",
           "name" : "data18",
           "children" : {
           "contains" : [ "8005_1" ]
           },
           "Parent" : false
           }, {
           "ID" : "8012_1",
           "name" : "data19",
           "children" : {
           "contains" : [ ]
           },
           "Parent" : false
           }, {
           "ID" : "8005_1",
           "name" : "data20",
           "children" : {
           "contains" : [ "8006_1" ]
           },
           "Parent" : false
           }, {
           "ID" : "8017_1",
           "name" : "data21",
           "children" : {
           "contains" : [ "8018_1" ]
           },
           "Parent" : false
           }, {
           "ID" : "8002_1",
           "name" : "data22",
           "children" : {
           "contains" : [ "8004_1", "8003_1", "8007_1" ]
           },
           "Parent" : false
           }, {
           "ID" : "8022_1",
           "name" : "data23",
           "children" : {
           "contains" : [ "8023_1" ]
           },
           "Parent" : false
           } ]
           }
           ];

    })
        .directive('expand', function () {
            function link(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$on('onExpandAll', function (event, args) {
                    scope.expanded = args.expanded;
                });
            }
            return {
                link: link
            };
        });
}());
```